# Peugeot rear brake location

Tags: brakes, seatpost, mixte

I have a 1985 Peugeot P16 (mixte). The Weinmann 730 sidepull rear brake was located at the seatstay bridge.

Q: Is it safe to relocate it to the gusset plate located behind the seat tube and attached to the intermediate stays (because i don't know the name of the head tube to rear drop out twin tubes!).

The brake, with a spacer, will physically fit, but i don't know if it's the right thing to do. Seems this would leave the seat stay bridge for rack & fender mounting.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, on my 1975 Peugeot UO18, the brakes are located on the intermediate stays and the seat stays are used for the rack mount.

The brake configuration is visible here.

[image]
(photo source: http://oldtenspeedgallery.com/owner-submitted/joans-1975-peugeot-mixte-uo-18/#.VWFRtmDDz88)

Comment: Beautiful bike :-)

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation and beautiful example picture/ link. I think repositioning the brake cleans up the back end considerably.

Comment: It was originally designed this way and makes for a very clean and efficient positioning of the brake cable. I wonder why someone relocated your brakes to the seat stays in the first place.

Comment: I don't know why. Just picked up the bike at a flea market for $45. The rear brake bolt did have 2 concave aluminum spacers gripping the seatstay bridge, so i do believe it was "factory" install.